# How to attach cloth to a rigged character.?

Tags: rigging, parent

I wan't to know in screenshots.sorry i can't explanation,i am new in blender.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice.

Comment: To request clarification from the author of a post, leave a [comment](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) below the post in question.